# Surjectivity of a given map

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a local ring. Then $f:R^\times\to (R/I)^\times$ induced by quotient map $R\to R/I$ is surjective. (Here, $I\subsetneq R$ is an ideal.)

Let $a+I\in (R/I)^\times$. Then there is $b+I\in (R/I)^\times $such that $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I = 1+I$ i.e. $ab-1\in I$. Since $R$ is local, its unique maximal ideal $M$ is $R\setminus R^\times$. Hence, $ab-1\in I\subset R\setminus R^\times$ so that $ab-1\notin R^\times$. I don't know how to proceed further. Could you help?

Comment: Do you know this result about the Jacobson radicals? The Jacobson radical is equal to $$\{r \in R | 1+rb \in R^{\times} \text{ for all } b \in R\}$$

Comment: @DuduBob Cool. You mean as $1-ab\notin R^\times$, $a,b\notin R-R^\times$ i.e. $a,b\in R^\times$. So the map is surjective right?

Comment: Yes, but this result is apparently an overkill. The answer below is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\in M$, then since $ab-1 \in I \subseteq M$ then $1 \in M$, a contradiction.

Therefore $a \in R \setminus M = R^\times$